# How to use variables in awk scripts

Tags: awk

I am having trouble in using variables in awk scripts.

```
myvariable = tolower(substr($1,0,2)) tolower(substr($2,0,8))
```

so I can use $myvariable in the script instead of using the above every time.

I have tried ,but it prints everything nothing cut from the strings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Awk is different from linux shell scripting.. you don't need to use `"$"` in front of variable names. In awk, `"$"` is special in its own way, for example it is  used to reference a field/line/record.

if you declaring your variable declare it like this

```
myvariable = tolower(substr($1,0,2)) tolower(substr($2,0,8))
```

that is, drop the $ in front of your **awk** variable **inside** your awk statement

if you have  a variable declare in your linux shell  and you want to use that variable in your awk script

You can assign your shell variable to awk like

```
awk -v awkvariable="$myshellvariable" '{...commands....}'
```

Comment: For normal variables you are correct, but $1, $2, etc are special. They are replaced by the first, second, etc. word on the line that is currently being processed. So the poster should use $1, $2, etc as he does, but $myvariable is incorrect, and as you say, he should just use myvariable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was really helpful.

Comment: `$myvariable` has a meaning: `myvariable` is converted to an integer, and then `$0` or whatever it is expands to that field.  e.g. `$NF` is the last field, because `NF` is the number of fields.

Answer (score 0):

AWK have three "types" of variables:

- one for accessing fields (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ...)
- a bunch of system variables (`NR`, `NF`, `FS`, `RS`, ...)
- user-defined variables (`my_var = 123`, `i = "hello"`, ...)

To print the lower to you simply write the variable name:

```
my_var = "john doe";
print my_var;
print NF; // Print Number of Fields
```

eg

```
echo john was here | awk '{print NF}' # 3
```

The interesting part is that you can mix system/user-defined variables with field variables (`$1`, ...) like so:

```
my_var = 2;
print $my_var; # print second field
print $NF; # Print last field (Using the "Number of Fields" variable)
```

eg

```
echo john was here | awk '{print $NF}' # here
echo john was here | awk '{print $(NF-1)}' # was
```